# Rails how to remove last comma in array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my JSON view I have:

```
[
<% @sog.each do |kon| %>
{"id":"<%= kon.id %>","titel":"<%= kon.titel.force_encoding("UTF-8") %>","url":"<%= kon.photo.image.url %>"},
<% end %>
]
```

How do I remove the last comma in the loop? The JSON is not working because there is a comma in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several options, but one is use `each_with_index` and add the comma iff it's not the last iteration.

You could `collect` JSON strings and `join` them with `","`, eliminating the need to check.

Or create a method that serializes the object to JSON, avoiding all the busywork in the view layer.

Comment: How to use the collect method in view?

Comment: I have used the each_with_index

Answer (score 0):

Another meaningful and simplest way of doing it would be

```
@json_obj = []

@sog.each do |kon|
   @json_obj << {"id":"kon.id",
                 "titel":"kon.titel.force_encoding('UTF-8')",
                 "url":"kon.photo.image.url"
                }
```

You don't need to worry about the comma anymore. Hope this helps.